# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Component')

Tags: reactjs, maven, tomcat, war

getting 404 error
war packaging through `mvn package` command.
local it is working, when we deploy to `tomcat` screen is not loading.

### routing..

```
<Route path='/demo/:id' exact component={demo}/>
```

### Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import userStore from "./store/userStore";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}>
    <Provider store={userStore}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);


reportWebVitals();
```

local it is working, when we deploy to tomcat screen is not loading.